# Removing PlotLine last element

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Im using HighCharts for listing values, and i dont know how to remove last PlotLine element, im trying with this:

```
removePlotLine: 5
```

But do nothing. Dunno why i have 5 PlotLine cause, i call only 4

```
data: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

[Here is the picture for easy understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvZkX.png)

Trying with this: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/plot-bands-and-plot-lines

Anyone know any solution? Please share with me :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you refer as a plot line is, actually, a grid line. It can be controlled with tick options. In your case it should be enough to explicitly set min and max - but it might depend on your other configuration.

```
yAxis: {
  max: 4,
  min: 0
},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/ud2p88nL/

See API for tick options: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-point-events-remove/

```
chart.series[0].data[0].remove();
```

Example has different type of chart but the API is the same.

More available in the API reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/